# NSProgressIndicator not working in El Capitan

Tags: macos, swift, osx-elcapitan

I have an OS X Swift app which works correctly in Yosemite, but the progress bar doesn't show in El Capitan. All else works normally in the "real" program.

I created a stub program to try to debug the problem, but I still can't get the progress bar to show. Using XCode 7.0.1 (7A1001) and created this from scratch

The test app takes a counter input (typed in) and should show a progress bar until count is reached. If the progress bar is unhidden it does appear, but doesn't refresh until the end, when it shows blue 100%. I've added progressBar.display() - no effect and I get the same with window.display() i.e. no change.

progCount is another field I put on the window to see if I could see the numbers ticking up, but that didn't show until the last number.

I used debug and saw the i value ticking up, and progressBar.doubleValue also incremented. It looks like a window redraw issue but I can't find what to do differently.  Remember too, this works on Yosemite.

Any help would be welcome, thanks

--- code fragment ----

```
@IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
@IBOutlet weak var progressBar: NSProgressIndicator!
@IBOutlet weak var counter: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var progCount: NSTextField!

//(a bit of housekeeping not shown)

@IBAction func countUp (sender: NSButton) {
    var i=0

    if counter.integerValue != 0 {
        progressBar.hidden = false
        progressBar.minValue = 0.0
        progressBar.doubleValue = 0.0
        progressBar.maxValue = counter.doubleValue

        while i < counter.integerValue {
            i=i+1
            progressBar.incrementBy(1.0)    
            progCount.doubleValue = progressBar.doubleValue
        }
        progressBar.hidden = true

    }
}
```

--- end ---

Answer (score 2):

Found myself in the same situation because I was updating my NSProgressIndicator from a tight loop on the main thread.
Prior to El Capitan I was just calling `displayIfNeeded` on the window the progress indicator was in and it worked fine. With El Capitan this broke and the progress indicator was stuck at 0%.
While I agree that rewriting my loop to run on a background thread and call into the main thread to update the progress indicator would be the best solution, in my case this unfortunately wasn't an option.

So the workaround I came up with is to first call `displayIfNeeded` on the window, followed by
`[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.001]];`

This gives the main runloop some time to breath and the progress indicator advances properly.
Yes, this is kind of a hack but so is running a tight loop on the main thread in a GUI app.

Comment: I have applied your workaround and I confirm that it can solve similar situations also in macOS Sierra:
 
http://github.com/gui-dos/Guigna/blob/d5e3ed7174e8881ee6899f1a0c6995a971f71b3b/Legacy/Guigna-Swift/Guigna/GuignaAppDelegate.swift#L87-L101

Comment: Can confirm this also works with sheets. (I am using a sheet to log progress on a long-running parsing operation.) It feels ugly and I hope some kind of Apple relief will be forthcoming, but it sure does the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not able to explain why your app might work differently on Yosemite versus El Capitan, but from the standpoint of the code that you shared, what you describe is its expected behavior. This is due to the code in your `countUp` function reaching their final values effectively instantaneously. Those are the values that you can see. To be able to see the intermediate values will require adjusting the timing of the updates.

To illustrate how you can observe a delayed update, a delay can be added as in the following modification:

```
while i < counter.integerValue {
    i=i+1

    let delay = Double(i) * 1.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))

    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        progressBar.incrementBy(1.0)    
        progCount.doubleValue = progressBar.doubleValue
      }
}
```

The delay makes it so the first update occurs instantly, the second update occurs 1 s later, the third update occurs 2 s after the first, and so on where the updates are scheduled on the serial dispatch queue for your main thread, the one that is appropriate for UI updates.

Comment: Thank you. On the Apple Developer boards another developer has verified the difference between NSProgressIndicator on El Capitan and Yosemite with an Objective C program. Looks like an OS bug somewhere...

Comment: You're welcome. That's an interesting bug. I hope that it gets resolved and that you will make a note of it here when it does.

Comment: Apologies for slow update. I still couldn't make this work with Daniel Zhang's addition, but have now achieved that with a self.window.display() inside the despatch_after construct.

Answer (score 0):

Try to tick "Can draw concurrent" in the editor for the progress bar. This might do the trick as a workaround, although it is probably not the real solution.